# Xsd Validation Error

Tags: java, xml, xsd, validation

i have a problem with the nested xsd files. I have this 3 files: Company.xsd Product.xsd and Person.xsd.

Company.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.company.org"
        xmlns="http://www.company.org"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:include schemaLocation="Person.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="Product.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name="Company">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Person" type="PersonType" 
                         maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="Product" type="ProductType"
                         maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Product.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:complexType name="ProductType">
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="Type" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>   
</xsd:schema>
```

Person.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
       <xsd:element name="SSN" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>   
</xsd:schema>
```

I try to validate this simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Company>
<Person>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <SSN>test</SSN>
</Person>
<Product>
    <name>Test</name>
</Product>
</Company>
```

but i had this error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Company'.

Do you know why??

Can someone help me??

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a namespace:

```
<Company xmlns="http://www.company.org">
... <!-- rest of XML --->
```

There are also some errors in your XML but it should be simple enough to fix them once you're getting more sensible output from the validator.

Comment: Ok tnk for reply, but my problem is not solved because i don't want specify the xmlns inside the TAG. In this case how i can mody the XSD schema??

Comment: Why don't you want to specify the namespace? Which part do you have control of, the XSD, the XML, or both?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your test XML has errors. This:

```
<Product>
   <name>Test</name>
</Product>
```

should be

```
<Product>
   <Type>Test</Type>
</Product>
```

Also your XML tags are lacking the namespace declaration. Without a namespace declaration, the tags are assumed to belong to no namespace at all. Since your schema puts the tags in a particular namespace (with URI `http://www.company.org`) then your XML needs to do the same if it is going to be able to validate.

For example you can do it like this in your `<Company>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Company xmlns="http://www.company.org">
   ....
</Company>
```

After this, everything validates fine.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://java-by-ash.blogspot.com/2012/07/xml-schema-validation.html) will show you how to validate XML files according to your XSD Schemas using JAXP parsing.